# Why can't I find <QTcpServer>?

Tags: c++, qt

My VS2010 can only `#include <Qt/qtcpserver.h>` but can't `#include <QTcpServer>`.

Qt assistant suggested `<QTcpServer>` be included to apply TCP server but it seems this header cannot be found by my VS2010, but it can find `<Qt/qtcpserver.h>` and these two headers seems to be the same.
Are they the same and why can't I find `<QTcpServer>` ?

PS:
I'm currently using Qt4 plugin with VS2010.
Here's a snapshot of my VS project files:
[image]

No `.pro` file there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have

```
QT += network
```

in your `.pro` file to get the Qt networking headers and library correctly set up for your project.

For the [Qt Visual Studio Add-in](http://doc.qt.digia.com/vs-add-in/index.html), look at the second tab of the [project settings](http://doc.qt.digia.com/vs-add-in/vs-addin-managing-projects.html#modifying-project-properties) dialog box.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a `.pro` file in my VS project.

Comment: Are you using some form of plugin in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Qt4 plugin.

Comment: If it's [this](http://doc.qt.digia.com/vs-add-in/vs-addin-managing-projects.html), look at the second tab of the first dialog box screenshot.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for.  Will you please add the link to your answer ?

Answer (score 1):

In your Qt project settings, add the network module. A guide with pictures:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/vs-add-in/vs-addin-managing-projects.html

Comment: Thanks! Coincidentally @Mat gave the same link !